# Using Uniform Resource Identifier syntax for the Web Gateway

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

We are using IBM MQ MFT WebGateway 7.5.0.4 to get files from central location. 
Problem is that we can only request all content of filespace like this: 
http://172.28.24.25:9080/wmqfte/filespace/7400_svc_transport?accept=JSON

Request with parameters fails: 
http://172.28.24.25:9080/wmqfte/filespace/7400_svc_transport?startafter=2010-08-26T13:00&accept=json

with an Error

BFGWI0032E 
The parameter ''startafter'' is not valid.

Severity 
20 : Error

Explanation

The parameter supplied by the user in the request is not valid. See the WebSphere MQ Managed File Transfer product documentation for valid parameters. 
Response 
Remove the invalid parameters and resubmit the request. See the WebSphere MQ Managed File Transfer documentation for valid values.

But we know for sure that parameters are valid and set according to documentation.

Where could be the problem?